# playwright python not able to select by class

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have the following element in a website that i want to fill in but for the life of me i cant get the script to actually "locate" it, i get timeout error even though the main page has been fully loaded (non-headless browser so i am certain all elements have been fully loaded). is there anyway i can select the element using the multiple css classes in the element?
Element:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" formcontrolname="companyName" maxlength="35" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Type Company Name">
```

my code for selecting using classes (doesnt work):

```
ric = 'ITUB'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36'
url = 'https://www.b3.com.br/en_us/products-and-services/trading/equities/listed-companies.htm?codigo=19623'

async with async_playwright() as P:
    browser = await P.chromium.launch(channel='chrome', headless=False)
    page: Page = await browser.new_page(user_agent=user_agent)
    await page.goto(url, wait_until='load')
    await page.locator('input[class=form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid]').fill(ric)
    await page.get_by_role("button", name="Search").click()
    await page.screenshot(path="screenshot.png")
```

I tried to select it using chained locators for the parent divs, placeholders, by its role, and id but i keep getting timeout error.

Comment: `".form-control.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid"` is a better selector than `class=` which is very rigid, requiring those exact classes in that exact order with that exact whitespace. That said, both appear correct on the single element you've shared out of context. Please share a [mcve] because the problem is very likely elsewhere.

Comment: @ggorlen I added a minimal example. thank you, but its still not selecting it for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those elements are inside the iframe `bvmf_frame`. You need to locate the frame first.

```
async with async_playwright() as P:
    browser = await P.chromium.launch(channel='chrome', headless=False)
    page: Page = await browser.new_page(user_agent=user_agent)
    await page.goto(url, wait_until='load')
    frame = page.frame_locator("#bvmf_iframe")
    await frame.get_by_role("textbox", name="Type Company Name").fill(ric)
    await frame.get_by_role("button", name="Buscar", exact=True).click()
    await page.screenshot(path="screenshot.png")
```